# How to run client server program on Google Colab Notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, google-colaboratory

I am able to execute the client-server programs in Python IDLE and in PyCharm but I am stuck while executing the same program on Google Colab.

The sample server code is:

```
s = socket.socket()
print("Socket Created")

s.bind(('localhost',9999))

s.listen(3)
print("Waiting for a Connection !!")

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    name = c.recv(1024).decode()
    print("Connected with :",addr, " ", name)
    c.send(bytes("Welcome to Socket Programming",'utf-8', name))
    c.close()
```

The sample client code is:

```
c = socket.socket()
c.connect(('localhost', 9999))

name = input("Enter your name: ")
c.send(bytes(name,'utf-8'))

print(c.recv(1024).decode())
```

On Google Colab, I pasted these codes in different notebooks and ran the server code first. I got the following error:

```
<ipython-input-1-0b55cff963bc> in <module>()
      1 import socket
      2 c = socket.socket()
----> 3 c.connect(('localhost', 9999))
      4 
      5 name = input("Enter your name: ")

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Then, I pasted the client code in the same notebook but in different code shells then I am not getting any output. Even after searching on Google, I am not able to find the solution to my problem. What wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, only one code shell runs at a time. Even with the "running" icon on.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).